# One-point compactification of R-Z

Tags: general-topology

It is not hard to prove that the compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ (the set of real numbers) minus a finite set, say $n$ elements, is homeomorphic to a union of closed curves whose intersection is a single point.  My intuition is that for $\mathbb{R}$ minus $\mathbb{Z}$ (the set of integer numbers) is homeomorphic to a union of countably many closed curves touching at only one point, but I do not know how to prove it.

Is my intuition true?  If not, what is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ minus $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "touching"?

Comment: @Spark Something homeomorphic to say the Hawaiian earring.

Comment: To the OP: the guess is fine, but you have to be careful about the neighbourhoods of $\infty$. Try to write things down, see what you get.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Oh, I first understood the sentence as "(compactification of $\mathbb{R}$) minus a finite set". Now I see what the question is.

Comment: When you say "homeomorphic to a union of countably many closed curves touching at only one point", does it mean Hawaiian earring or a quotient space of countably many disjoint union of $S^1$s?

Comment: @Spark That's what the OP should figure out, of course!

Answer (score 8):

One point compactification of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is homeomorphic to the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). The explicit homeomorphism can be given by following:

the interval $(n,n+1)$, where $n\in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$, is sent to the circle of radius $1/(2n+1)$, and the interval $(-n, -n+1)$, where $n\in\{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$, is sent to the circle of radius $1/(2n)$.

One thing you need to be careful of is its topology near $\infty$. In the one point compactification, open sets containing $\infty$ are complements of compact sets. In Hawaiian earring, open set containing $\infty$ contains all circles except for finitely many of them. In $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, compact sets are finite unions of compact sets in some interval $(n,n+1)$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ so they correspond exactly.